# Composing an Ecto [v1] query with a dynamic amount of where filters

Tags: elixir, ecto

This is a theoretical question but assume the data structure cannot change and that this is definitely how we want to do the query. This question is more to get a better understanding of **how `where` filters would be composed dynamically** rather than actually wanting to get the results from a query like this.

Imagine a database with a Car table in which each car has a `manufacturer_id` column that contains an ID such as "BD324" or "GM512", with "BD" & "GM" considered as prefixes.

We need to do a lookup on the car table such that cars get returned when their `manufacturer_id` prefix matches a given set of prefixes. So, given a list of prefixes:

```
prefixes = ["BD", "GM", "EX", "RD", "DE"]
```

..we'd want to return all cars that have a `manufacturer_id` that starts with *any* of those listed. i.e (LIKE x **OR** LIKE y **OR** LIKE z).

The following Elixir/Ecto code would search for one prefix:

```
search_prefix = Enum.at(prefixes, 0) <> "%"
from c in Car, where: like(c.manufacturer_id, ^search_prefix)
```

How would we go about building up the `where` clause based upon the `prefixes` list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ecto seems to be lacking a simple way to join dynamic parts of a query with `OR`, but I may have missed something. Please correct me if I am wrong.

However, you could use an equivalent [`ANY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN14122) query, which I claim is both easier to read and simpler to build:

```
SELECT * from cars
 WHERE manufacturer_id LIKE ANY(ARRAY['BD%', 'GM%', 'EX%', 'RD%', 'DE%']);
```

To create this kind of query with Ecto, you can use a [`fragment`](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1):

```
prefixes_like = prefixes |> Enum.map(&"#{&1}%")
from c in Car,
  where: fragment("? LIKE ANY(?)", c.manufacturer_id, ^prefixes_like),
  select: c
```

Comment: Thanks! Spoke to José on IRC and this is indeed the way to go (at least for now). If the requirement you have is AND though, rather than OR, you can use a reduce: `Enum.reduce prefixes, query, fn prefix, acc -> from q in acc, where: like(q.manufacturer_id, ^(prefix <> "%")) end`

Comment: or_where queries were added in Ecto 2.1 https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/commit/640e8f5f7f97eab68e4eebcd517803f71d90ebc1#commitcomment-18945603

Answer (score 5):

You can think of composing query as a data transformation:

```
prefixes -> query with multiple where conditions
```

To do this you need to reduce one data structure to another, and Ecto 2 provides `or_where` which fits your need.

Below is an example:

```
def filter_by_prefixes(query, prefixes) do
  Enum.reduce prefixes, query, fn prefix, query ->
    filter_by_prefix(query, prefix)
  end
end

def filter_by_prefix(query, prefix) do
  or_where(query, [c], like(c.manufacturer_id, ^"#{prefix}%"))
end

# Then build the query
Car |> filter_by_prefixes(prefixes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! This was written before Ecto 2 but this is certainly the way to go now.